# Derive the curvature in terms of a parametrization in the complex plane $z=z(t) $

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I was asked to show that $$\kappa=-i\frac{z''}{z'}=\text{Im}\frac{d\text{log}z'}{ds}$$

for a general parametrization $z=z(t)$. I know that the curvature is the rate of change of the unit tangent vector, but I have no idea how to derive this formula. Please help.

Comment: There are $t$ and $s$ here. Is this intended, and what does the $'$ mean then?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter s means arclength

Comment: You tagged this as differential geometry, but gave no context about how generally you want to prove this. Are you asking whether this holds on a general complex manifold? Regardless, this essentially just follows from the real valued case - just recall the canonical isomorphism between $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Hi Brevan, I didn't tag this as differential geometry. I think this Robert Lewis guy changed my tags.

Comment: @davidh:  yes sir I did so tag.  Because I think this problem straddles both differential geometry and complex analysis.  Cheers!

Comment: @davidh:  you might check out the book ***Advanced Geometry of Plane Curves and Their Applications*** by C. Zwikker, Dover Press, free PDFs available though you might have to search a bit for it.  Awesome!